# How to test controller that contains multipartfile as a parametr with restassured

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, rest-assured

I have problem testing my rest controller with libray rest assured.

MY rest controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = MENU_CATEGORY_ID)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> addCategoryItem(
            @PathVariable Long menuCategoryId,
            @RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile imageFile,
            @Valid @RequestBody CategoryItemDTO categoryItemDTO) throws IOException {

        Owner owner = userService.getCurrentOwner();
        CategoryItem categoryItem = categoryItemMapper.map(categoryItemDTO);
        menuCategoryService.addCategoryItemToMenuCategory(menuCategoryId, owner, categoryItem, imageFile);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
    }

@Test
    @Tag("owner")
    void shouldAddCategoryItem() {
        //given
        Long menuCategoryId = 1L;
        CategoryItemDTO categoryItemDTO = someCategoryItemDTO();

        File file = new File("resources/static/images/mcchiken.png");

        //when
        Response response = addCategoryItem(menuCategoryId, file, categoryItemDTO);
        //then
        assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.CREATED.value());
    }
default Response addCategoryItem(
            final Long menuCategoryId,
            final File imageFile,
            final CategoryItemDTO categoryItemDTO
    ) {

        return requestSpecification().urlEncodingEnabled(false)
                .pathParam("menuCategoryId", menuCategoryId)
                .multiPart("imageFile", imageFile, "multipart/form-data")
                .body(categoryItemDTO)
                .post(CATEGORY_ITEMS + MENU_CATEGORY_ID)
                .then()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.CREATED.value())
                .extract()
                .response();
    }
```

it throws me an exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Content-Type application/json is not valid when using multiparts, it must start with "multipart/" or contain "multipart+".

Comment: Did you try `.multiPart("imageFile", imageFile`)?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

May be adding

**.contentType("multipart/form-data")**
.multipart("imageURL",imageFile)

can resolve this issue.

As exception says -> *"an exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Content-Type application/json is not valid when using multiparts, it must start with "multipart/" or contain "multipart+". "*

Comment: After these changes I have another error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot serialize because cannot determine how to serialize content-type multipart/form-data

Comment: Do you have any form parameters ? Can you provide full code that you are referring to.